# Chart JS Legend Styling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, chart.js

I've created a Chart JS chart and generated the legend separately so that I can move it over to the right of the chat - that bit is fine and works but the legend itself has styled it's self as a standard bullet list with bullet points in place of the colour key. The labels have generated with no issues it's just the actual coloured boxes that I'm missing.

CSS:

```
.legend {
   width: 50%;
   position: absolute;
   top: 100px;
   right: 20px;
   color: @light;
   font-family: @family;
   font-variant: small-caps;
   font-size: @size + 2;
}
```

JS:

```
 // Dummy Data
    var data = {
        labels: [
            "Fuel Consumption (Miles)",
            "Distance Travelled (Miles)",
            "Distance Remaining (Miles)",
            "Fuel Cost (Pounds)",
            "Time Driving (Minutes)"
        ],
        datasets: [
            {
                data: [300, 50, 100, 25, 120],
                backgroundColor: [
                    "#FF6384",
                    "#36A2EB",
                    "#FFCE56",
                    "#F86301",
                    "#FFFFFF"
                ],
                hoverBackgroundColor: [
                    "#FF6384",
                    "#36A2EB",
                    "#FFCE56",
                    "#F86301",
                    "#FFFFFF"
                ]
            }]
    };

    var options = 

{
    segmentShowStroke: false,
    animateRotate: true,
    animateScale: false,
    percentageInnerCutout: 50,
    tooltipTemplate: "<%= value %>%",
    responsive: false,
    legend: {
        display:false
    }
}

// Today's Chart
var today = document.getElementById("today").getContext("2d");
var myDoughnutChart = new Chart(today, {
    type: 'doughnut',
    data: data,
    options: options
});

document.getElementById('legend').innerHTML = myDoughnutChart.generateLegend();
```

HTML:

```
<canvas id="today" style="width: 40%;"></canvas>
<div id="legend" class="legend"></div>
```

Here's a JSFiddle of the issue:
https://jsfiddle.net/WebDevelopWolf/kbqa8fcz/

Comment: Can you make an working example?

Comment: Please create a snippet and as exactly what do you want to be done from your snippet.

Comment: please provide working fiddle or runnable code so that i can fix the issue..

Comment: Updated with a fiddle

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Here is the fixture.** The legends are actually creating the colors but as its a custom legend you have to write a little css for workaround.

```
.legend ul li{list-style:none;}
.legend ul li span{ width:50px; height:15px;display:inline-block; margin-right:5px; }
```

> Below is the working code:

```js
// Dummy Data
    var data = {
        labels: [
            "Fuel Consumption (Miles)",
            "Distance Travelled (Miles)",
            "Distance Remaining (Miles)",
            "Fuel Cost (Pounds)",
            "Time Driving (Minutes)"
        ],
        datasets: [
            {
                data: [300, 50, 100, 25, 120],
                backgroundColor: [
                    "#FF6384",
                    "#36A2EB",
                    "#FFCE56",
                    "#F86301",
                    "#FFFFFF"
                ],
                hoverBackgroundColor: [
                    "#FF6384",
                    "#36A2EB",
                    "#FFCE56",
                    "#F86301",
                    "#FFFFFF"
                ]
            }]
    };

    var options = 

{
    segmentShowStroke: false,
    animateRotate: true,
    animateScale: false,
    percentageInnerCutout: 50,
    tooltipTemplate: "<%= value %>%",
    responsive: false,
    legend: {
        display:false
    }
}

// Today's Chart
var today = document.getElementById("today").getContext("2d");
var myDoughnutChart = new Chart(today, {
    type: 'doughnut',
    data: data,
    options: options
});

document.getElementById('legend').innerHTML = myDoughnutChart.generateLegend();
```

```css
.legend {
   width: 50%;
   position: absolute;
   top: 100px;
   right: 20px;
   color: @light;
   font-family: @family;
   font-variant: small-caps;
   font-size: @size + 2;
}
.legend ul li{list-style:none;}
.legend ul li span{ width:50px; height:15px;display:inline-block; margin-right:5px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.bundle.js"></script>
<canvas id="today" style="width: 40%;"></canvas>
<div id="legend" class="legend"></div>
```